# Como usar PHP no VSCode?

Tags: php, servidor, visual-studio-code

Boa tarde!
Eu utilizava a IDE PHP Storm para programar em PHP, e ela permite a conexão com um servidor remoto e execução do código lá no servidor.
Agora, migrei para o VS Code e gostaria de saber como posso programar em PHP nessa IDE. Onde insiro os dados do servidor remoto? Como faço para executar um script? Obrigado!

Ps: Eu já instalei algumas extensões como IntelliSense do PHP e PHP Debug, mas ainda assim não sei o que fazer.

Ps2: Utilizo servidor do LocaWeb, essa programação em PHP seria para uma página web.

Comment: Tenha em mente que nem todos os programas possuem as mesmas ferramentas. Phpstorm é uma IDE, enquanto o VS Code é editor de texto com alguns plus. Certifique-se primeiro que o VS Code é capaz de fazer o que deseja. Aliás, por que mudou de o PHP Storm aparentemente satisfazia suas necessidades?

Comment: Sim, já pesquisei e é possível utilizar o PHP em VS Code (tanto que existem inúmeras extensões para facilitar esse processo), mas não encontrei nada sobre como, de fato, codificar e subir o código no servidor (afinal, por isso estou aqui fazendo a pergunta). E deixei de utilizar o PHP Storm pela maior praticidade do VS Code (pesquise um pouco a respeito dos prós dessa ferramenta), além de que o VS Code é totalmente gratuito, diferente do PHP Storm.

Comment: Não sei exatamente como funcionaria para o seu caso, mas por exemplo com o Git, quando vc faz o Commit ele envia o arquivo alterado direto para o repositório, ai basta vc dar um refresh na página que ela já pega o que foi mudado etc. Então o VS Code comunica sim com diretórios remotos, vc tem é que ver como vc vai enviar o arquivo pro seu server, uma forma como falei é configurando o Git lá, ou talvez com Docker, mas ai não tenho conhecimento pra opinar muito.

Comment: penso que quem marcou essa questão como ruim não se deu ao trabalho de entender que isso é válido a partir do momento que alguém deseje usar. @LucasVicente, gostaria de uma ajuda sua, fiz as instalações dos plugins, mas por algum motivo continuo recebendo alguns erros. Teria como entrar em contato diretamente comigo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VSCode não é um IDE como o PHPStorm, então você não tem nativamente como colocar os dados do servidor e outras facilidades que o PHPStorm dava nativamente para você.

O que eu faço é ter meu VSCode com as extensões mais recomendadas do PHP instaladas, para isso é só você abrir o editor e ir na barra lateral na parte de extensões, na busca digite: `@recommended php`.

Depois, você pode utilizar o terminal integrado do VSCode (através da tecla de atalho ou então através da aba de comandos `ctrl + shift + p` digitando "Open new terminal". A partir daí você pode desenvolver normalmente, é possível utilizar o servidor nativo do PHP com `php -S` no próprio terminal, afinal o PHP é só um arquivo de texto que é interpretado no browser.

Existem outras extensões como as abaixo para poder facilitar um pouco:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=brapifra.phpserver
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PrimaFuture.open-php-html-js-in-browser
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MehediDracula.php-namespace-resolver
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=neilbrayfield.php-docblocker
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FrogTheFrog.php-project

Se você usa git o VSCode já tem a extensão nativa do git, se não você pode buscar outras extensões com FTP para poder acessar o servidor.

Comment: Obrigado meu jovem!